# What do the sort and timestamp parameters to /preapply/block mean?

Tags: baking, rpc

If you look at [the documentation for .../preapply/block](https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/rpc.html#post-block-id-helpers-preapply-block), you see two parameters: *sort*, and *timestamp* But there is no explanation for what these do. The RPC help does not even mention them:

```
$ ./tezos-client rpc list /chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/preapply/block

Available services:

  - POST /chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/preapply/block
      Simulate the validation of a block that would contain the given
      operations and return the resulting fitness and context hash.
```

Can someone explain what these two parameters mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When the `sort` flag is set, the operations in the block will be sorted before being pre-applied
- The `timestamp` may be used to explicitly apply a timestamp to the block. When omitted, the current system time is used

Comment: Sorted by what?
`timestamp` just puts whatever I provide back into the returned result?

Comment: The ordering of the operations is protocol specific. In the current active protocol version (006), the operations are sorted by their type: `Endorsement < Seed_nonce_revelation < Double_endorsement_evidence < Double_baking_evidence < Activate_account < Proposals < Ballot < Manager_operation` and furthermore manager operations are sorted by their counter (smaller first)

Comment: The block is validated with given timestamp and it's also added to the block's shell header.